# Verilog tasks yielding different results compared to direct coding

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

The two simplified code sections yield different results (this is the only difference)

1. Wihtout task decleration

   ...
   if (A) wait (flagA);
   if (B) wait (flagB);
   ...
2. with task decleration

   ...
   task test(input flag)
   begin
   wait(flag);
   end
   endtask

   if (A) test(flagA);
   if (B) test(flagB);
   ...

Would very much appreciate any insights - what is the difference between the two?

Thanks!

Comment: @shlopkin you just need to come up with a small example that is compilable and reproduces your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that input arguments to tasks are by default copied by value upon entry to the task. If the actual argument changes while the task is suspended (i.e. the `wait`) the task does not see the updated value of the argument.

One way to accomplish what you want in SystemVerilog is passing the argument by reference `ref`:

```
task test(ref logic flag);
  if (A) test(flagA); if (B) test(flagB); ...
```

Passing by ref has some stricter type requirement, and you cannot pass a `wire` by reference.

The other way is globally referencing `flag` the same as you are doing with signals `A` and `B`